# Define a function that returns a list of prime factors

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a complete beginer when it comes to programming and need help with this. Ive been tasked with creating a function that returns a list of prime factors of a given number.

i have already made a separate function to check for prime numbers, and a function to list prime factors up to a given number but when i try perform a check if said prime is a factor the list is returned empty.

```
#A1 Q1, Flow control
def isprime(N):
    if N < 2: return False
    for n in range(2,N-1):
        if (N % n) == 0: return False
        if n >= N//n: break
    return True

def factors(x):
    pf = []
    for n in range(x+1):
        if isprime(n) is True and n % (x+1) == 0: 
            pf.append(n)
    return pf

pf2 = factors(10075)
print(pf2)
```

so for 10075 pf2 should return [5, 13, 31]. instead i get an empty list.

Comment: There's no reason to modulo `(x+1)` rather than just `x` and your modulo operation is reverse for what you're trying to do. Try `if isprime(n) and x % n == 0:`

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, seems to be working just fine now. I best read up more on what % actually does.

Comment: Think of `A % B` as like `A / B` but it gives you the remainder. A mnemonic to help is that `/`and `%` look kind of similar